# File missing after copying to file system partition

Tags: system-installation, hidden-files

I was a using XP with 4 partitions in hard disk. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in one of the formatted partition thus making it bootable either in XP or Ubuntu. 
Recently I had copied some 10GB of movies from External hdd to 'tmp' folder in 'file system' partition of Ubuntu. The partition space got reduced. After restarting I found that the files were missing from the tmp folder.

Another problem was the partion had 53.3 GB unused space of 59.6GB.

After copying movies ofit was showing 43.3GB of 59.6 GB . But once the movie files went missing it is showing 43.3 GB used of 49.6GB.

I would like to know what went went wrong? 
What happened to these files? If the files were lost then why the partition space got consumed? 
Kindly provide a solution.

Comment: After recovering the files, reboot and check the size, used amount, available amount and used% of the partition with the command `df -h`  You should also notice, that 5% of the size (in the linux file system `ext4`) is reserved for the system, so that the regular user is not allowed to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The **`tmp`** folder in the 'file system' partition of Ubuntu is a temporary folder, and it will be flushed, the content will be removed at shutdown and reboot.

So I am sorry, but the files are gone. Maybe, if you are lucky, some of the file data are still there and can be recovered with [PhotoRec](http://cgsecurity.org), but it can be a lot of work to identify them among all other file data, that PhotoRec can find.

To avoid overwriting more data, please stop using this system, boot from another drive (and try to recover files). Do *not* mount this 'file system' partition of Ubuntu.